# Keeping JPA EntityManager open - Connection Pooling

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, connection-pooling

In one RESTful web-service we have developed (Spring MVC - Rest) , we make about 50 calls to the DB. This takes around a minute to complete. We could see that after each call, the JPA entity manager is closed and a new one created, as per the logs below

```
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
17:18:16.399 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.o.j.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler - Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
```

We suspect that this is taking time, since the query when executed on its own is taking minimal time. How do we make sure that the JPA connection remains open throughout? Please note that this is a GET call, and we are not doing any updates. How can we achieve connection pooling? Is the closing\opening of the JPA connection this expensive?

This is where we declare the EntityManager programatically (ApplicationConfiguration)

```
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.skyteam.api.flightstatus.domain.persistence");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
```

I have tried the below using c3p0 of hibernate for connection pooling, but it didn't help.

```
properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "5");
properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "20");
properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "300");
properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "50");
properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period.timeout", "3000");
```

Any help? (Note - the previous questions which seemed similar didn't help)

Comment: post content of `dataSource()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are creating dataSource in method `dataSource()`.

I believe, you have two options:

1. Wrap that data source into `ComboPooledDataSource`. It also
   implements `javax.sql.DataSource` interface and add pooling to the
   DB connections.
2. Don't create data source explicitly, but let JPA create it.
   Something like this:

   ```
   properites.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver","...");
   properites.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url","...");
   properites.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user","...");
   properites.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password","...");
   ```

Comment: Really really thanks for your answer! Solved my problem. Can you please explain why creating dataSource explicitly would cause this problem?

Comment: Because default dataSource provided by Spring Boot would be using connection pooling by default (assuming you have connection pooling library on classpath).